# react native ble plx - Bluetooth is not supported in ios

Tags: react-native

When I start device scan by calling the method startDevcieScan(), most of the time "bluetooth is not supported" alert comes. This happens only in ios. I am unable to figure out why its happening.I tested the code on actual devices - iphone 5s, 6s and ipad.

Below is the code snippet:

```js
let that = this;
let deviceList = [];
let count = 0;

that.manager.startDeviceScan(["1802"], null, (error, device) => {
    if (error) {
        try {
            alert(`${error.message}`);
            Log.info(`BLE scan error: ${error.message}`);
        } catch (e) {
            Log.info(`BLE scan error: ${error}`);
        }
        return;
    }


    let localDeviceList = deviceList;
    let exists = false;

    localDeviceList.map((d) => {
        if (d.id == device.id) {
            exists = true;
        }
    });

    if (!exists) {
        deviceList.push(device);
        this.homeScreen.setState({listBLEDevices: deviceList});
        let arr = this.homeScreen.state.availableDevices;
        arr.push({id: device.id, name: device.name, connected: false});
        this.homeScreen.setState({availableDevices: arr});
    }
});
```

};

Comment: This may be related to the scan starting before the bluetooth state is "PoweredOn", see: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/573